# PowerShell checking paths in different namespaces?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a problem with automation, granting permissionto to resources.

The resource can be accessed by entering the actual path and by namespace. example "`//res/..`" and "`//res2/..`"

I have a database in which I have created records that have connections to active directory, and gives permissions through groups in AD.

Is it possible to write a script that first checks if the path exists
example: `Test-Path -Path" C: \ Windows "`

and then check if there is such an entry by first checking the physical path and then namespace?

Users use the server name interchangeably. To avoid this I would have to create groups in AD with different server names.

I am asking for help in finding a solution

Comment: Try and be more careful where you insert spaces and where not.. `"// res / .."` --> `"//res/.."`. `Test-Path -Path" C: \ Windows "` --> `Test-Path -Path "C:\Windows"`

Comment: thanks, I changed it